# Wordpress "get_template_directory()" returning incorrect path

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use `get_template_directory()` to load files from a particular theme, but the path is incorrect and is causing errors when trying to call particular functions from the directory.

`get_template_directory()` is returning `...html/wp-content/themes/mysite.com v2` instead of the correct directory, which is `...html/wp-content/themes/mysite-v2` (with a dash, instead of a space).

Where is `get_template_directory()` defined and how to I change to to refer to the correct directory?

Comment: That merely produces `mysite.com%20v2`, doesn't account for the missing `-` in the directory path.

Comment: Why do you have a dash in your TLD?

Comment: Still produces a path with the space.

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski what does TLD stand for?

Comment: Did you try removing the dash from your theme folder name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to use Wordpress' `update_option` function to update to the correct theme folder.

```
update_option('template', 'mysite-v2');
```

Doing this before calling `get_template_directory()` successfully updated *all* of the calls to `get_template_directory()` in my theme folder to reflect the the theme that I passed in.

Answer (score 1):

A **top-level domain (TLD)** *(i.e. `.com`, `.org`, `.net`)* cannot contain a dash (-).

Your browser is trying to interpret the meaning of the dash directly following your domain and is unsuccessful therefore replacing the dash with a url-encoded string.

**Update:**
You can use Wordpress' `get_template_template_uri()` and concatenate the location of the file you want in relation to the active theme's root folder.

[Check out the API for this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)

Comment: See my edits above, the folder for the *theme* is in the folder `mysite-v2`, for some reason `get_template_directory()` is still looking for `mysite.com v2` as the name of the theme folder.

Comment: Are you trying to build a url to use in a `href` or include a file in a `php` template?

Comment: I'm trying to include files in a php template, but there are multiple references  to `get_template_directory()` in the PHP files I'm trying to load, so it's not a viable option to manipulate the path in each instance.

Comment: The problem with the answers, as I just commented, is that I would have to change `get_template_directory` in all instances..

Comment: @Himmel: which instances? You should be using this function as a black-box without having to manipulate its implementations.

Comment: There was no manipulation of its implementation, there was just a lot of reliance on the function. All of the functions that relied on `get_template_directory()` were returning the incorrect path to the theme. By using `update_option`, I updated the path to the theme folder, thereby correctly referencing the theme folder in all instances where `get_template_directory` was used within the theme (see answer below).